# How can I predict the stopping angle of a spinning wheel?

Tags: javascript, math, graphics, game-physics, physics

I'm trying to predict the angle in which a spinning wheel will stop if it is slowed down to a rotational speed of 0 over a certain time.

For example; 
If my wheel is spinning at +20 degrees per tick, and it reaches a set angle of say, 720 degrees, where I then begin to slow it down to a stop over 5 seconds, what angle will it rest at.

I have been looking at a lot of existing questions and material for this and am aware of the sort of maths I need to be working with; getting the deceleration speed and rotational velocity, but I'm struggling to use this information to predict an end angle.

This was a particularly useful resource but I am still unsure on how to translate this math into a predicted resting angle.
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142761/how-to-model-a-very-simple-spinning-wheel

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be on-topic for Stack Overflow. Assuming a time-independent angular acceleration `alpha`, and where the angle is `theta` and the angular velocity is `omega` we get: `theta(t) = theta_0 + INT(omega(t'))dt' | t' = 0 to t' = t` where: `omega(t) = omega_0 + alpha * t`, we get the quadratic: `theta(t) = theta_0 + omega_0 * t + 1/2 * alpha * t ^ 2`, where `_0` denotes an initial value. If angular acceleration is not constant, that'll complicate things a little. Either way, it's a relatively simple example of a problem requiring calculus.

Comment: The general solution for a time-dependant angular acceleration would be `theta(t) = theta_0 + omega_0 * t + INT(INT(alpha(t'')dt'' | t'' = 0 to t'' = t')dt' | t' = 0 to t' = t`, where `alpha(t)` is the time-dependant angular acceleration. If `alpha` depends more closely on some other parameter (like an `omega`-dependant angular acceleration), this form could be changed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the mechanism that stops it, but if we assume that it's simple friction, then deceleration is constant and the answer is easy:

If it starts off at 20 degrees per tick, then the average speed during the slowdown period is 10 degrees per tick, so 720 + 10 * 5 * ticks_per_second degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming constant deceleration (dry friction), the angular speed decreases linearly. Hence, the *average* speed is the half* of the *initial* speed, or

```
A / T = Ω / 2
```

where `A` is the traversed angle, `T` the time to stop and `Ω` the initial angular speed.

Hence

```
A = T Ω / 2
```

---

*For the same reason that the area of a right triangle is the half of the area of the bounding rectangle.